# Google Drive - How to empty trash from code (programmatically)?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

Please help me to integrate a project with Google Drive.
The problem is that Google Drive trash folder is never emptied, so eventually Google Drive synchronization with desktop stops working due to the lack of space.

I need either to configure the trash to not keep deleted files (preferred option) or empty it programatically from C# code (less preferred), or other programing language (last resort option) .

How do I empty Google Drive trash from code or script or whatever?

Answer (score 6):

The Google Drive API doesn't expose a method to empty the trash but it has a `delete` method to delete files permanently, without sending them into the trash:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete

You can also retrieve files from trash by checking the `trashed` label of the [Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) and then call `delete` on them.

Comment: Thank you very much for these clarifications, i also discovered what deleting files through WebDav (thanks to Dav Pocket http://dav-pocket.appspot.com/) do not moves files to trash bin, but apparenty execute your DELETE command, so this solution goes with minimal coding, and i will give a try to it. 

Sorry i cannot mark your answer as usefull, since i have not enough "reputation" points

Answer (score 2):

Here a shorter version, i tried using the above solution, but with no luck.

```
function emptydrivetrash() {
  Drive.Files.emptyTrash();
}
```

All you have to do is to enable de drive api, in the Resources Menu-> Google Advanced Services and in google developers's console...

Comment: I don't know about that. I have this exact script running once a day without any issues...

Comment: Note that this uses the *advanced* drive service, which needs to be activated separately. For complete confusion, compare the G Suite "Drive Service" (using the `DriveApp` object, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) and the "Advanced Drive Service" (using the `Drive` object, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive). I have yet to understand why there are two APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution:

1) Create an empty script on your drive

2) Paste the following code:

```
function doGet() {
  try{
  authorize();    
  var key = "YOUR DEVELOPER KEY";
  var params = {method:"DELETE",
                oAuthServiceName: "drive",
                oAuthUseToken: "always"
               };  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/trash?key="+key,     params);  
  }
  catch(error)
  {
    MailApp.sendEmail("<some email>", "EMPTY TRASH BIN ERROR:<br>"+error);    
    return;
  } 
}

function authorize() {
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("drive");
  var scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?     scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");  
}
```

3) Deploy the script as a web application

4) Click on the clock on the top bar and create a trigger that invokes the doGet method

This will empty the trash for the user that is creating the trigger.