# Google Drive - How to empty trash from Google API

Tags: google-drive-api

I searched and found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960526/google-drive-how-to-empty-trash-from-code-programmatically):

```
function doGet() {
  try{
  authorize();    
  var key = "YOUR DEVELOPER KEY";
  var params = {method:"DELETE",
                oAuthServiceName: "drive",
                oAuthUseToken: "always"
               };  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/trash?key="+key,     params);  
  }
  catch(error)
  {
    MailApp.sendEmail("<some email>", "EMPTY TRASH BIN ERROR:<br>"+error);    
    return;
  } 
}

function authorize() {
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("drive");
  var scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?     scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
```

I "fixed"

```
MailApp.sendEmail("<some email>", "EMPTY TRASH BIN ERROR:<br>", error);
```

to get errors in my mail, and put my developer key (some like this ZHjkMQP3dNiA24LmOvZ5WZ2v-_-APMcbEtHD6q) in var key but yet I get authoritation error:

Exception: Error OAuth:

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the API reference will help you https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/
To send a file to the trash you need to use Files: trash(see Google drive API reference)
which requires the fileId of the file you need to move to the trash. And its method is POST and not DELETE. 
So maybe something like this will work out

```
  var params = {method:"POST",
                oAuthServiceName: "drive",
                oAuthUseToken: "always"
               };  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{THE fileId of the file to be trasshed}/trash?key="+key,     params);  
  }
```

This should move a file to the Trash. If you want to delete a file permanently you need to use Files: delete(see Google drive API reference) 
So maybe if you just replace "trash" with {FileId} in the url it will work out.

UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{FileId of the file to be deleted}?key="+key,     params);

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to delete files, I want to empty trash (because files are moved to trash by another program). And that part seems to be correct:  
  
emptyTrash  DELETE  /files/trash  Permanently deletes all of the user's trashed files.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Empty Trash API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/emptyTrash) contains an easy way to empty your trash directly from the page