# Automatically delete file from Google Drive trash

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, delete-file

There are several articles, but I am not able to put a code together to run it successfully.

One article I have looked at: [Permanently delete file from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749906/permanently-delete-file-from-google-drive/32749203#32749203)

I would like to automatically delete the Google Drive trash folder items every hour or so. Prefer every 10 minutes. 
Google need to implement this useful feature.

Comment: here is another article I attempted to use with no success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960526/google-drive-how-to-empty-trash-from-code-programmatically/11960708#11960708

Comment: Drive.Files.EmptyTrash();  is the method. It works. But I want to make it in a script to auto pilot it. help please

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/iassael/google-drive-trash-cleaner

Answer (score 6):

As stated on [ [Permanently delete file from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749906/permanently-delete-file-from-google-drive/32749203) ], you can enable the Drive API in order to get access to the method, through Appscript. Take a look at [appscript quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) to ensure that your implementation can support calling the API every ten minutes.

You can use this solution:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('emptyThrash')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(1)
      .create();
}

function emptyThrash()
{
  Drive.Files.emptyTrash();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. i get "ReferenceError: "Drive" is not defined. (line 10, file "")" when i run the code via script.google.com. i believe i had similar issue before on top of other issues. so its still not working code.

Comment: i forgot to enable Drive API. let me try again and report back. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just used

```
function you-can-put-anything-here()

{
  Drive.Files.emptyTrash();
}
```

then added trigger in google script with email alerts. set trigger to 1 hour and bam it works. to call emptyTrash, Had to enable Drive API to ON under Advanced Google Services and Drive API ENABLED under Google Developer Console. Save the file and it ran without any issues. Thanks Rivero for guidance.

Comment: If you turn it on under Advanced Google Services and play your script, it will give you a link to the project in GDC to enable it.  I never use GDC so going there first was not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

i succeeded deleting a file from terminal using following curl command.

```
curl -X Delete -H 'GData-Version: 3.0' -H 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.Ci9rA4GFUvdEbOBtjA9ZPSq9_W7klt5hmyAMf5Jq8R1EdhiJIZwYqAgnjZsWG7SdWQ' https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bwhnkm8opwXBQVZ5RmZuMWVUTzg
```